# Excel - How to return rows based on multiple colums having a yes

Tags: excel

I have a sample table below.

I want to return all rows that have "Yes" based on any possible Heading combination. For example, how do I return all rows where Heading1 is "Yes" and where Heading2 and Heading3 are "Yes". Or where Heading 5 and heading 6 are "Yes"?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQKzn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following table:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | H1 | H2 | H3 |
| 2 | I1 | Y | Y |  |
| 3 | I2 |  | Y | Y |
| 4 | I3 | Y |  | Y |

We can first have all the columns mark themselves as having a `Y` or whatever you want like this

```
=IF(B2=$A$1,ROW(B2),"")
```

where `$A$1` is the location of the word you want to compare it to
this copies the data in the table and puts it somewhere else like this

[image: Screenshot of Excel spreadsheet similar to the one written in markdown]

Then you can have a row of cells with this formula in them to concatenate the now row values to form a single result

```
=CONCAT(B6:B8)
```

If you want to add some separators between the row numbers you can add them after the first and before the second answer.

Note that a single formula can be used for each column but that would make writing it tedious and difficult to expand.

Also note that if you want to do anything more complicated, you can look into macros and not using Excel altogether and using a database software instead.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*. Here an array version, that has as input the input set (`in`) and column positions of the headings (`cols`), delimited be comma. Put the following formula in `I2`:

```
=LET(in, A2:F10, cols, 1*TEXTSPLIT(G2,,","), set, N(DROP(in,,1)="Yes"),
 cnts, MMULT(CHOOSECOLS(set, cols), SEQUENCE(ROWS(cols),,1,0)),
 f, FILTER(in, cnts=ROWS(cols), "No rows match"), IF(f=0, "", f))
```

**Note**: You can use `BYROW` as follows instead of `MMULT`. It is a matter of personal preferences: `BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(set, cols), LAMBDA(r, sum(r)))`.

and select the heading column positions in cell `G2`. Here is the output for columns `2` and `3` together (`AND` condition is ensured by: `cnts=ROWS(cols)`):

[image: output]

as you can see `item2` and `item9` satisfy the condition. In the case the input columns returns and empty set, it returns the message: `No rows match`.